# Error loading belongsTo relationship in Ember 2

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember.js-2

I am having issues loading a `belongsTo` relationship - no errors get displayed, and no requests sent. The UI just remains blank. Given the following models:

**project.js**
    import DS from 'ember-data';

```
export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    items: DS.hasMany('line-item', {async: true}),  
    customer: DS.belongsTo('customer', {async: false})  
});
```

**customer.js**

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr(),
    email: DS.attr(),
    projects: DS.hasMany('project', {async: true})  
});
```

The relationship between **project** and **customer** exists. When accessing the projects endpoint, the project gets correctly returned:

```
{  
   "data":{  
      "type":"projects",
      "id":"3861b834-e270-4296-b7be-9aca55676874",
      "attributes":{  
         "created":"2016-04-27T22:36:01.061349Z",
         "modified":"2016-04-27T22:36:01.061477Z",
         "name":"Sample name",
      },
      "relationships":{  
         "customer":{  
            "data":{  
               "type":"customers",
               "id":"9242bd41-6bb0-41ed-b5f3-21df26486d9e"
            }
         },
         "items":{  
            "meta":{  
               "count":0
            },
            "data":[  

            ]
         }
      }
   }
}
```

However when trying to access the customer, nothing happens (with nothing I mean: no console output, no request to the customers endpoint etc. The UI just fails to load):

```
this.get('project').get('customer');
```

Accessing other attributes works (including the project's items).

Any idea as to where I am going wrong?

Comment: I believe since the relationship is async, then the get is returning a promise.  `project.get('customer').then((customer) => {
   // now we can work with the customer
});`

Comment: Thanks snew. Unfortunately this doesn't work - the problem seems to be `project.get('customer')` - this is where it fails.

Comment: Is the return value undefined or actually something?

Comment: No, nothing - there is no return value. It seems to fail somewhere in trying to get the customer.

Comment: So a couple things.  Is the json you posted above from the network tab in Chrome when you visit a route or just by simply accessing the API?  Also, could you post your route code?

Comment: Thanks snew. The json comes from the network tab. I will update my question with the route.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `project` model you defined `customer` as `async: false`, which means it should be provided when loading the projects from your server. From the json output you provided the customer data is missing.

So either include the `customer` record when returning the json from your server or make customer `async: true`, so it will get loaded when calling `project.get('customer')`